# Delphi/Firemonkey How to call Settings.System.canWrite(context) (Android)

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, android-permissions

I'm using Delphi 10.3 Community Edition and want to use the WRITE_SETTINGS in my application to set the brightness.
I could get it managed to implement this procedure to call the settings dialog:

```
procedure RequestWriteSettings;
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJSettings.JavaClass.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

I can call this procedure in my application, the dialog appears and I can set the necessary permissions.
But I don't want to call this procedure permanently, because that's not user friendly.
I need to check if the WRITE_SETTINGS permission is already set, but I don't know how to implement this in Delphi/Firemonkey.

What I could find is that one has to call the "Settings.System.canWrite(context)" function, but I only can find samples for java.
Calling these kind of java routines in Delphi isn't that easy. I'm searching around already for some weeks and tried "things on my own", but still without success.

Can someone provide the code line how this routine has to be called in Delphi?

Thanks so much in advance!
MPage

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't help in any way. I already tried many samples, but none of it reflects my described problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code for checking WRITE_SETTINGS:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNI.Provider, Androidapi.JNI.Net, Androidapi.Helpers;

procedure TForm1.RequestWriteSettingsButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not TJSettings_System.JavaClass.canWrite(TAndroidHelper.Context) then
    StartWritePermissionsActivity
  else
    ShowMessage('System says app can write settings');
end;

procedure TForm1.StartWritePermissionsActivity;
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
begin
  LIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJSettings.JavaClass.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
  LIntent.setData(TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString('package:').concat(TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName)));
  TAndroidHelper.Context.startActivity(LIntent);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks so much Dave, that's what I've been searching for!

Comment: @XingFuZhuanYun select the answer to reward Dave

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I found a solution for myself, but I think Dave's is better. ;-)

That's what I found with the "trial and error" method:

`function HasWriteSettings: Boolean;
    begin
    // Call canWrite to check for permission WRITE_SETTINGS
     Result := TJSettings_System.JavaClass.canWrite(TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationContext);`

```
end;
```